# How do i set Recipients property in Outlook.AppointmentItem?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

In this excel VBA code i am trying to create a new appointment in outlook and what i want is to email that appointment i.e. i want to invite users for the appointment.
I am not sure if i need to create a new outlook.recipients object for this thing or i am not using the .Recipeint.Add property properly.

```
Sub app()

    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application 
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.AppointmentItem 

    Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    With OutMail

       .Location = " happening"
       .Subject = " Event check "
       .Start = "8:00 PM" & Format(Date)
       .End = "9:00 PM" & Format(Date)
       .Body = "this is event details"
       .Recipients.Add ("someone@gmail.com") ' This line is not working
      ' .Display
       .Send

    End With

End Sub
```

I am getting application-defined or object defined as error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appointments are personal and for you only.

You have to change it to a meeting first before you can add recipients.

To do so, add `AppointmentItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting` to your code. So for your code it would be

```
Sub app()
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application 
Dim OutMail As Outlook.AppointmentItem 

Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

With OutMail
   .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
   .Location = " happening"
   .Subject = " Event check "
   .Start = "8:00 PM" & Format(Date)
   .End = "9:00 PM" & Format(Date)
   .Body = "this is event details"
   .Recipients.Add ("someone@gmail.com") ' This line is not working
  ' .Display
   .Send

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes .MeetingStatus was the property i was not aware of. Thanks. But what i figured out that .Recipients.Add() property was not working in this case, maybe because this property is for recipients in the address book. So i have modified the code above by using .RequiredAttendees property and it seems to work fine now. And I still use Outlook 2007.

Comment: @DevUtkarsh Email addresses are always valid recipients. But I'm glad to see you got the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a pop-up like this?

[image]

If so and if you are clicking "Deny", then that could explain your error.  This happens because the object model guard is put in place to prevent hackers from gaining access to your email recipients through the outlook object model.  See this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864479%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: The problem is that he isn't setting the `MeetingStatus` property to change the Appointment to a Meeting.

Comment: Sorry roryap, this was not an issue. The issue was the meeting status and adding recipients. Though thanks for your effort.